# @Component with parent?

Tags: java, spring

Is there any way to use `<bean parent="someParent">` with @Component annotation (creating spring beans using annotation)?

I would like to create spring bean that has "spring parent" using @Component annotation.

is it possible?

Comment: Can't you just use inheritance? Autowiring in base class will work the same way.

Comment: @Tomasz Nurkiewicz I have spring parent bean defined in xml (it has some property's set to "default" values). That is not something I can change.

Comment: I added an answer to further explain my idea. Can you elaborate a little bit more why it does not suit your needs? Why can't you change the parent definition in XML? I'm afraid it is not possible to reference parent from annotation...

Answer (score 6):

Following my comment, this piece of XML

```
<bean id="base" abstract="true">
    <property name="foo" ref="bar"/>
</bean>

<bean class="Wallace" parent="base"/>
<bean class="Gromit" parent="base"/>
```

is more or less eqivalent to this code (note that I created artificial `Base` class since abstract beans in Spring don't need a `class`):

```
public abstract class Base {
    @Autowired
    protected Foo foo;
}

@Component
public class Wallace extends Base {}

@Component
public class Gromit extends Base {}
```

`Wallace` and `Gromit` now have access to common `Foo` property. Also you can override it, e.g. in `@PostConstruct`.

BTW I really liked `parent` feature in XML which allowed to keep beans DRY, but Java approach seems even cleaner.

Comment: Yours example won't work if `base` bean will be define in XML, with or without creating artificial `Bean` class and `Wallace` and `Gromit` will be created by component-scan.

Answer (score 0):

Just came across the same Construct.. (a general abstract parent Class which used Beans - with context.xml-declaration for an potential Implementation that was injected by Component-scan)

This is what I could have done in the @Component Class:

```
@Autowired
public void setBeanUsedInParent(BeanUsedInParent bean) {
   super.setBeanUsedInParent(bean);
}
```

---

..what I ended up doing (better, since it makes clear that the injection works on the object not on classes) - and if you are able to modify the parent Class:

```
// abstract getter in parent Class
public abstract BeanUsedInParent getBeanUsedInParent();
```

..leave the actual Beans as well as their injection up to the actual implementation (the @Component Class):

```
@Autowired
private BeanUsedInParent beanUsedInParent;

@Override
public BeanUsedInParent getBeanUsedInParent() {
   return this.beanUsedInParent;
}
```