# When a SubClass which is a spring bean calls method of SuperClass which is also a spring bean, the autowired field in SuperClass is null

Tags: spring, spring-boot, nullpointerexception

I have a SuperClass.

```
@Component
public class SuperClass {
    private TestBeanSuper testBeanSuper;

    public SuperClass(){}

    @Autowired
    public SuperClass(TestBeanSuper testBeanSuper) {
        this.testBeanSuper = testBeanSuper;
    }

    public void test() {
        testBeanSuper.test();
    }
}
```

a SubClass.

```
@Component
public class SubClass extends SuperClass{
    private TestBeanSub testBeanSub;

    public SubClass(){}

    @Autowired
    public SubClass(TestBeanSub testBeanSub) {
        this.testBeanSub = testBeanSub;
    }

    public void test() {
        super.test();
    }
}
```

When I call subClass.test(), NullPointerException occurred.
The testBeanSuper in SuperClass test method is null.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at com.spring.demo.SuperClass.test(SuperClass.java:18) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.spring.demo.SubClass.test(SubClass.java:18) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.spring.demo.TestController.test(TestController.java:19) ~[classes/:na]
```

[image]

Could someone tell me why this happened?

And when I debugged, I found that testBeanSuper is inside the SubClass instance. The testBeanSuper is defined as private in SuperClass, why it is inside the SubClass instance?
[image]

Comment: If I m not mistaken Spring will not create a bean of supper class, that s why the null pointer is triggered

Comment: in `SubClass` constructor you don't call `super` class constructor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you might not have any Inheritance in your `Bean Definition`. Super-class members, loaded into memory during creation of respective child-class according to the Java OOP model, is not going to be referencing your explicit `Spring Bean`.
I. E. you have Java inheritance, but you should also define Bean Inheritance, if you'd want to achieve what you ask in your question. Otherwise, your explicit `component` is not necessarily the one where your "child" `component` inherits from.

This is also the answer for your

> And when I debugged, I found that testBeanSuper is inside the SubClass
>   instance. The testBeanSuper is defined as private in SuperClass, why
>   it is inside the SubClass instance?

second question.

**One more general suggestion**:

whenever you deal with multiple beans connected/wired to each other in any form, in the most cases, better to use `setter-injection` to avoid any cycling problems or `.. bean is in creation state` problems.

I would also like to suggest you to read about [Bean Definition Inheritance](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#beans-child-bean-definitions).

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
I understood I need to specify Bean Inheritance, but could you tell me how to add bean inheritance when annotation is used. I searched and the solutions are all about how to add bean inheritance in XML.

Comment: Not to delay the answer: I'm away for a while for now, so can't do the good research, and I can't recall it from the top of my head at the moment.. but what if you define your custom `@Bean` in the `@Configuration`, instantiate and initialize your object, and then register it into your context?

Comment: Thank you. I found the solution which just remove @Component from SuperClass and change constructor injection to field injection. Then everything is OK.

Comment: I thought I also mentioned setter-injection.. hah :), at least, I was thinking about that as well. During the instantiation, try to avoid all cycling dependencies.. and therefore, use setter as much as possible.

Comment: Also, I'd very much appreciate if someone, who voted this answer down, would explain to me why they did so.

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be no annotation-based alternative for the XML `parent` bean mechanism and the corresponding [issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/10251) has been closed. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8270320/component-with-parent) provides a workaround though: if you autowire the member instead of the constructor, the `TestBeanSuper` will be properly injected.

```
@Component
public class SuperClass {
    @Autowired
    private TestBeanSuper testBeanSuper;

    public SuperClass(TestBeanSuper testBeanSuper) {
        this.testBeanSuper = testBeanSuper;
    }

    public SuperClass(){}

    public void test() {
        testBeanSuper.test();
    }
}
```

On the matter of private members showing up in the debugger - there are already [excellent explanations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4716040/do-subclasses-inherit-private-fields). While the **subclass** does not inherit private members nor has access to them, there is only one **object** at runtime which needs to have access.